# FCM message not received in android app

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implement FCM in my project and its working fine. 
But not received message while follow below steps.

1. Open Settings>Apps>MyFCMApp
2. Click "Force Stop"
3. Send message from Firebase Console
4. Open MyFCMApp
5. Wait for message received

But not received pending message and send message again on its received.
I have check force stop after open app on token not change.

How to resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well There are 2 types of Firebase Cloud Messaging.

1. Display Messages: This type of FCM only works when the app is in foreground, which I suspect you are using.
2. Data Message: This works both in foreground and background which is what you want.

There is really no way to explain on here. And if I am not violating StackOverflow rules, For more understanding check out this  [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkJPZvfaFXk).

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SmsGateWay", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    editor.putString("Refresh_token", token);
    editor.commit();
    editor.apply();


}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
    // sending gcm token to server
    Log.e(TAG, "sendRegistrationToServer: " + token);
}
```